# Express body parsing

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express middleware that has its own `write` function on the response object. I am capturing the response bodies for use elsewhere. I am using `body.toString()` to capture the body.

However, some of the response bodies are malformed in out output. For example I might capture:

```
'\u001f�\b\u0000\u000fb\u0007T\u0000\u0003�WɎ�6\u0010�\u0015E�\\�nR�|ʆ\u0004Y\u000f�\u00009\u0004�@K��iJTH�...'
```

When the server is actually responding with a JSON object. I'm guessing there is an encoding issue here. Any help on resolving? I have tried `body.toString("utf8")` with no luck.

Update: showing the code:

```
function(req, res, next) {
  var write = res.write;
  res.write = function(body) {
  var rawBody = body.toString();
```

Comment: You will need to show a bit more code. Can you try to condense your issue down into a reproducible piece of code?

Comment: @loganfsmyth updated, see above

Comment: I'm guessing body isn't what you think it is.  The response looks like binary.  Unless you show us the code that created body, we probably can't help.

Comment: @AlexMA it appears things are coming through gzip'ed. I think that is my issue.